# How to Add Values to Columns which is define at runtime (WPF Datagrid)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My XAML (Contains two Static Columns)

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource=" 
{Binding }">
        <DataGrid.Columns>          
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Code Behind for Datagrid Collection.

```
 ObservableCollection<Users> list = new ObservableCollection<Users>();
    class Users
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Adding columns at runtime from Code Behind

```
private void AddColumnsAtRuntime()
    {
        grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            Header = "Address",
            Binding = new Binding("Address") 
        });
    }
```

[image]

Populating Collection

```
 private void AddRow()
    {
        list.Add(new Users()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "John"
        });
    }
```

[image]

**What i want is - How can i add Values to both static and dynamic columns, static columns will contain some Style trigger**

Comment: if you are binding to Address (`Binding = new Binding("Address") `), then you should have Address property in User class

Comment: how can i define property at runtime to existing class which is already a Type for List.

Comment: You would need to add a column to your datagrid to bind to any new property. If you want something which is a dynamic type then a datatable is the first candidate to consider. You can easily add columns dynamically. If that does not suit then you could consider an observable dictionary. http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/

Comment: if i use DataTable then i am not able to bind static columns in my xaml code. you are right i need a dynamic type for ObservableCollection

Comment: @GhanshyamKumar: Why can't you use `DataTable`? You can bind to a column of a `DataTable` just like you bind to a property of a CLR object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding to an `ObservableCollection<Users>`, you could bind to the `DataView` of a `DataTable` to which you can add columns dynamically:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id"));
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
list = dataTable.DefaultView;
...
list.Table.Rows.Add(1, "John");
...
list.Table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Address"));
list.Table.Rows[dataTable.Rows.Count - 1]["Address"] = "address...";
```

The XAML is exactly the same as before:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```